# How do I export a kivy app as a .apk? (android app)

Tags: python, android, kivy

I have a very basic kivy app that I would like to test and make sure I can get it to work on my phone. I'm new to this stuff so please pardon my lack of knowledge.

From what I understand, once I have my kivy app written, i need to export it as a .apk file. I am looking for a program or something that will allow me to do this on windows 10. I know buildozer is a thing, but it only works on linux. I am wondering if there is an equivalent to that for Windows 10.

Bonus points if it can also be exported for iOS as well.

Here is the app code. My understanding is that this is compatable to be exported as a .apk but i figure I'll put it here just in case:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        #Creates another grid named self.inside (which will become the sub grid)
        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 2

        #Each one of these blocks is a new widget
        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text = "First Name: "))
        self.name = TextInput(multiline = False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.name)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text = "Last Name: "))
        self.lastName = TextInput(multiline = False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.lastName)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text = "Email: "))
        self.email = TextInput(multiline = False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.email)

        self.add_widget(self.inside) #Adds sub-grid to main grid

        #This creates the button
        self.submit = Button(text="Submit", font_size = 40)
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.pressed) #Binds that button to the function pressed. This is a method inside this class
        self.add_widget(self.submit)

    def pressed(self, instance):
        name = self.name.text #Grabs the text from self.name
        last = self.lastName.text
        email = self.email.text

        print("Name: ",name, "Last Name: ", last, "Email: ",email)

        #This clears the text by making the text box be ""
        self.name.text = ""
        self.lastName.text = ""
        self.email.text = ""

class myApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    myApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Kivy documentation [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html)

Comment: It is a long list of dependencies and pip doesn't work for them. How do I install the dependencies for python-for-android?

Comment: Scroll down to the Installing Dependencies Section:https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/